# Is it possible to reference a foreign key in an database to another database?

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-9

I understand that it is possible in `MySQL`, but I can not figure out how to reference a foreign key in one `sqlite` database to another `SQLite` database.

Below is an example that I attempted to replicate based on my online research, only to discover that it is for `MySQL`. I can not seem to find any questions about `SQLite` DB referencing another `SQLite` DB via Laravel.

Below snippets shows for example say we have 2 `SQLite` databases; `sqlite-a` and `sqlite-b`, where we want to reference a foreign key from `sqlite-a` to reference a key in `sqlite-b`.

```
Schema::connection('sqlite-a')->create('Changelog', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $db = DB::connection('sqlite-b')->getDatabaseName();

    $table->id();
    $table->dateTime('date');
                
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->nullable()->unsigned();

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on(new Expression($db . '.User'));

    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The error that I have encountered when I tried to do `php artisan migrate` is that there is a syntax error in the referencing.

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "/": syntax error (SQL: create table "Changelog" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "date" datetime not null, "description" varchar not null, "user_id" integer, "created_at" datetime, "updated_at" datetime, foreign key("user_id") references /path/to/sqlite/database/b.sqlite.User("id"))

I would love to hear from anyone who has dealt with this before or has a solution.

At this point, I believe it is not possible that two `SQLite`databases can reference each other. In `MySQL`, this is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When talking about foreign keys, SQLite's built-in foreign key constraints do not work across databases. But you can make cross database calls:

```sql
attach 'database1.db' as db1;
attach 'database2.db' as db2;
```

```sql
select
  *
from
  db1.SomeTable a
    inner join 
  db2.SomeTable b on b.SomeColumn = a.SomeColumn;
```